# How do I rotate JUST the element clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have six `#card` elements, and each one has a `.content` element inside of it that is supposed to rotate when that `#card` is clicked on. However the problem is that when I click on a `#card`, all six instances of `.content` rotate.

I want JUST the instance of `.content` inside the clicked on `#card` to rotate.

Here is the jQuery that was causing that problem:

```
var rotated = false;
$('#card').click(function(){
    if(!rotated){
        $('.content').css({
            "transform": "rotateX(180deg)"
        });
        rotated = true; 
    }else{
        $('.content').css({
            "transform": "rotateX(0deg)"
        });
        rotated = false;
    }
});
```

I tried this to fix it but to no avail:

```
var rotated = false;
$('#card').click(function(){
    if(!rotated){
        $(this + '.content').css({
            "transform": "rotateX(180deg)"
        });
        rotated = true; 
    }else{
        $(this + '.content').css({
            "transform": "rotateX(0deg)"
        });
        rotated = false;
    }
});
```

Is there a simple solution to this? I'm newish to jQuery and don't know the full extent of the syntax.

Comment: "I have six #card elements"  IDs need to be unique within a document.  Use classes for anything you have more than one of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$(this + '.content').css({
```

to be

```
$(this).find(".content").css({
```

Answer (score 1):

Toggle classes is so much easier:

```js
$(".card").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".content").toggleClass("rotated");
});
```

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
}

.content {
  background: rgb(15, 33, 155);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(15, 33, 155, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 26, 85, 1) 99%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0f219b', endColorstr='#ff1a55', GradientType=1);
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotateX(180deg)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=card>
  <div class=content>1</div>
</div>
<div class=card>
  <div class=content>2</div>
</div>
<div class=card>
  <div class=content>3</div>
</div>
<div class=card>
  <div class=content>4</div>
</div>
<div class=card>
  <div class=content>5</div>
</div>
<div class=card>
  <div class=content>6</div>
</div>
```

P.S. Don't use more than one ID on the page, use classes.